# Contrast Stretching for colore images with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i'm working in matlab and i wanted to apply the Contrast Stretching for grey scale image and also RGB image , 
so for the grey scale i've tried this one and it worked

```
      clear all;
      clc;
      itemp = imread('cameraman.tif'); %read the image
      i = itemp(:,:,1);
        rtemp = min(i);         % find the min. value of pixels in all the 
       columns (row vector)
        rmin = min(rtemp);      % find the min. value of pixel in the image
        rtemp = max(i);         % find the max. value of pixels in all the 
       columns (row vector)
       rmax = max(rtemp);      % find the max. value of pixel in the image
       m = 255/(rmax - rmin);  % find the slope of line joining point 
      (0,255) to (rmin,rmax)
       c = 255 - m*rmax;       % find the intercept of the straight line 
       with the axis
       i_new = m*i + c;        % transform the image according to new slope
       figure,imshow(i);       % display original image
       figure,imshow(i_new);   % display transformed image
```

this is for greyscale image ,

the problem is that  that i don't know how to do for the RGB image 
any idea? how to implement that? 
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the function `stretchlim` ([reference](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/stretchlim.html)) be useful for your purpose?

> Find limits to contrast stretch image.
>
> Low_High = stretchlim(RGB,Tol) returns Low_High, a two-element vector
>   of pixel values that specify lower and upper limits that can be used
>   for contrast stretching truecolor image RGB.

```
img = imread('myimg.png');
lohi = stretchlim(img,[0.2 0.8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
rmin = min(i(:));
```

Then it computes the minimum over all values in `i`. This will work for RGB images also, which simply are 3D matrices with 3 values along the 3rd dimension.

The rest of your code also applies directly to such images.